# Retrofit pass parameter through post and get result

Tags: android, retrofit2

This is my Api.php

```
$command=$_POST["command"];
if($command=="getUsers"){
    getUsers();
}
elseif ($command=="getNews")
{
   getNews();
}
```

I'm using retrofit to show result in my android app. I  need to pass parameter Command through Retrofit Post and Get a result at the same time.
what's the solution?

Comment: I think i would be easier to provide you an answer if you provide both commands as URLs instead of PHP code. Android developers are rarely experienced in PHP. I don't know what the command is ... is it a body or a query param of the http request?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this example from Retrofit website:

```java
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("user/edit")
Call<User> updateUser(@Field("first_name") String first, @Field("last_name") String last);
```

Source: https://square.github.io/retrofit/